# CSS transition effect upward height doesnt work

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

EDITED **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/magnix2k/zqdsj7cv/)**
[image]

The goal to display a transition upward height when the button is hovered, but this line of CSS `.btn-position:hover ~ .bg-transit { height: 430px !important;}` seems it expands downwards instead upward. Is there a way to transition UPWARD?

I dont want to add any JS to it.

HTML

```
<div class="career-wrapper-positions">
  <div class="section-positions">
    <div class="position-wrap">
        <div class="position-box" id="video_interpreter">
            <div class="employees"><img src="http://staging.svrs.com/assets/images/careers2018/position-lady1-1.png" alt="SVRS | Video Interpreter positions"></div>
            <div class="position-tited-top-bg"></div>
            <div class="position-box-info">
                <div class="position-header"><h5 class="h5-careers18">CUSTOMER SERVICES</h5></div>
                <div class="position-subheader" id="subheader1">positions</div>
                <div class="position-p">Individually, passionate about the work. Collectively, the largest sales workforce in the world.</div>
                <div class="btn-position">
                    <button onclick="location.href='#'" class="position-btn" id="btn1-position">Apply now</button></div>
                <div class="bg-transit"></div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.section-positions { margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; }
.position-header { text-align: center; }
.position-header p { margin-top: 0; }
.position-wrap { height: 525px; position: absolute; z-index: 10; width: 100%; text-align: center; display: flex;  margin-top: 175px; }
.position-box {  width: 209px !important; height: 330px; display: block;  margin: 20px; background-color: #231f20; z-index: 2;}
.position-tited-top-bg { width: 209px !important;  height: 20px; background-color: #231f20; -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, 2deg); transform: skew(0deg, 2deg); margin-top: -15px; position: relative;z-index: -2;  }
.position-header { height: 15px;color:#ffbb11; font-size: 22px; font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif; font-weight: 400; }
.position-subheader { color: #ffbb11; margin-top: 10px; font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;}
.position-p { color: #fff; padding: 0 10px 0 10px; font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif; font-size: 14px; margin-top: 10px; line-height: 20px; }
.position-btn { background-color: #ffbb11; width: 150px; height: 41px; border: none; border-radius: 8px; font-size: 1em; font-weight: 600; cursor: pointer; margin-top: 50px;  }
.position-box-info {  padding-top: 10px;  }

/* this is the button to trigger a new height size transition of the background box  */
.bg-transit {  width: 209px !important; height: 338px; display: block;   background-color: #ff0000; z-index: -1; position: relative; top: -280px; transition-property: height;  transition-duration: 0.5s;}
.btn-position:hover ~ .bg-transit { height: 430px !important;}

.position-btn:hover { background-color: #231f20 !important; color: #ffbb11 !important; border: #9c7002 solid 1px; }
.employees { position: absolute; margin-top: -210px; width: 207px; margin-left: 5px; z-index: 9999;}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.position-btn:hover ~ .position-box-info` selects all siblings `.position-box-info` that come after a `.position-btn:hover`. Since `.position-box-info` is actually the parent of the `.position-btn` element, nothing gets selected. In fact, you can't select a parent from a child, so you either have to add a class with javascript or change your HTML.

Also, you seem to miss a `</div>` closing tag.

Comment: I just updated the HTML and it works, but it transitions downward instead of upward. Im not sure what else I can to make it work.

Comment: It's positioned relative. Try positioning it `absolute` with `bottom: 0px;` rather than a `top` property and that should anchor it to the bottom, resulting in the height changing upwards. Don't forget changing it's parent to relative then though, so it anchors to the bottom of the parent box rather than the `body`.